# One giant SQL statement or many small SQL statements?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-performance

I have a scenario where I need to check for 10,000 different specific names against a table with about 60,000 records of names.  Assuming caching is not relevant, generally speaking, for performance purposes, is it better to:

(1) Break up into mini-queries so that there are maybe 200 different names per query?

or

(2) Write one mongocious sql statement with 10,000 "OR" clauses?

Comment: You missed out number 3: Do it another way entirely. I would write the list to a separate table/temp table or something, then filter using a join.

Comment: @JonEgerton Posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed out number 3: Do it another way entirely:

I would write the list to a separate table/temp table or something, then filter using a `join`/`exists` or whatever.

Comment: +1 - Definitely my preferred way.  And given that most (all?) RDBMSs have 'load' utilities, this'll probably be the _fastest_ way, too.

Comment: Probably the only time this wouldn't work well though would be if the names change completely on each request. This would mean removing the table, re-creating it, inserting the records, then making the `JOIN`, each time.

Comment: @Radu I think that's why X-Zero mentioned 'load' utils, which would save a ton over separate inserts

Answer (score 1):

One first observation is that usually RDBMSs have a limit of the size of the query string which you might exceed with so many ORs.

So a solution would be to write a stored procedure and do it in a loop.

Ignoring this, given that in case (1) the data would be accessed more times than in case (2), the latter one is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Or #4 - Use an IN() query in batches.  About 1000 usually works pretty well:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN ('str1', 'str2', 'str3', ...)

It's not perfect, but there's no temporary table involved, and MySQL is pretty good about optimizing IN().